# Automatically block IP who requests certain URL using Fail2ban

Tags: iptables, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, fail2ban

From [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/416926/automatically-block-ip-who-requests-certain-url) question I followed [this](https://serverfault.com/a/675731/287944) answered.

I make a filter and enabled it inside the fail2ban config file. This is the filter:

```
# Fail2Ban filter to web requests for home directories on Apache servers

[INCLUDES]

before = apache-common.conf

[Definition]

failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*/wp-login.php/.*$
ignoreregex =
```

Fail2ban can't start because of error (I can not see the error specifically from the log), what's wrong in my syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Delimiters like slashes and dots used in things like "test.php" need escaping for regexes.  Testing yours on a [testing site](https://regex101.com/r/Y5We9T/1) gives the following error:

/ An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash ()

Adding the backslashes would correct the syntax error, but you would still need to test it to see if it matches the request correctly.  Hope this helps!

```
^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*\/wp-login.php\/.*$
```

**Edit - I saw the link to the regexes Fail2ban uses, which is the Python regex, found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).  It is good reading for fail2ban.