# fail2ban error with regular expression

Tags: nginx, fail2ban

I am attempting to ban a specific url in my jail.local configuration. The url is

```
Add_Product.php?union+select <-- Lots more follows this

ERROR  NOK: ('Unable to compile regular expression \'^(?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>[\\w\\-.^_]*\\w) -.*"(GET|POST).*/Add_Product.php?*union+select\'',)
```

This url doesn't actually exist. We don't even run this query in our databases.

Here is the rule in my jail.local

```
[sql-union-select-attack]
enabled = true
filter = sql-union-select-attack
logpath = /var/log/nginx/*access.log
maxretry = 1
findtime = 10
bantime = 60000
```

Here is the rule in my filter.d/sql-union-select-attack.conf

```
#The SQL Injection attempt with "union+select+" in the URL     
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*/Add_Product.php?*union+select+0x5e2526
ignoreregex =
```

Do I have a syntax error in my jail rule? I tried to use [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/416926/automatically-block-ip-who-requests-certain-url) question as a reference since I needed something similar. This attack attempt is bogging down my server.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try plugging it in at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tvMvdh/1)? It points out the syntax error in your regex.

Comment: The error it is showing is "* The preceding token is not quantifiable"

Comment: That's correct, you can't have zero or more of a `?` as that character is also special. It's not clear why you have the `*` there.

Comment: I'm trying to capture anything after Add_Product.php? and before union+select. There are id numbers after the php query string, and they're always different.

Comment: Then you probably meant to use `.*`

Comment: Yes, I changed it to that, restarted fail2ban, checked my syslog and didn't get the error again.

Comment: Actually, this is not working at all due to the ^<HOST> at the beginning. My nginx logs do not have the host at the beginning. It's actually the port number. :(

Comment: If you altered your log format, you should edit your question appropriately. We don't know anything that you don't tell us!

Comment: Lucky there is [FILTER document](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.11/FILTERS) that shows you how to not write DoS susceptible filters (like you are) and how to use `fail2ban-regex` to design and test queries.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I didn't touch the log format. I changed the regex.

Comment: @danblack I will look into the susceptibility of my regex. Thanks for the tip. I also use Regex101.com which is helpful.

Comment: But you said [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/936159/fail2ban-error-with-regular-expression#comment1214618_936159) that you changed the log format!

Comment: No. I changed the regex in the filter.d/sql-union-select-attack.conf to include '.*'. I didn't change the log format of the access logs themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my problem. I tested on a VM and it dropped my connection successfully.

```
failregex = ^\d{4} <HOST> -.*\"(GET|POST).*Add_Product.php.*union+select
```